# How to Boot Memtest86 from a Ventoy USB

Tags: memory, usb-device, bootable

I downloaded [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) with the intention of adding it to my [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/) usb, so that I could boot a machine for a memory test.

Although Ventoy claims to support img files, it wouldn't boot the `memtest86-usb.img` file I extracted from the zip I downloaded from [memtest86.com](https://www.memtest86.com/). Upon trying, I got to this screen:

> This IMG file is NOT supported now.
>
> ????????  IMG ??
>
> press ENTER to exit (?? ?? ???) . . .

Screenshot:

[image]

So, then I tried to convert the `memtest86-usb.img` file to an ISO using two different tools.

**Using ccd2iso:**

```
sudo apt install ccd2iso
ccd2iso memtest86-usb.img memtest86-usb.iso
```

That failed:

```
Unrecognized sector mode (0) at sector 0!
```

**Using iat:**

```
sudo apt install iat
iat memtest86-usb.img memtest86-usb.iso
```

That locked up indefinitely on the last line below (5222476), with 100% CPU :

```
Iso9660 Analyzer Tool v0.1.3 by Salvatore Santagati
Licensed under GPL v2 or later

Detect Signature RAW 2 at 2489646
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 2490706
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 2491174
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3858846
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3859906
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3860374
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3867774
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3867778
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 3867782
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 4529386
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 4529414
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 4529418
Detect Signature RAW 2 at 4635258
Detect Signature RAW at 5222476
```

After a few minutes I ultimately had to kill the process.

I guess I just need to give up on booting this with Ventoy and just dedicate a whole USB to this very small image. I hoping, however, someone has a recommendation as to how to get this working with my Ventoy USB.

Comment: I updated my question to include the error from Ventoy. Since, the [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com) includes memtest86. I'm just going to put it's ISO onto my Ventoy USB instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but solved it by making sure the PC BIOS were set to use UEFI. In my case there's an option to try both, failure to boot resulted from the PC Trying to boot MemTest86 in BIOS mode first, rather than UEFI.